# YQL Blacklisting

Tags: yahoo, yql, blacklist

I'm developing an online deck editor, [Proxymang](http://www.yellosoft.us/proxymang/), and YQL can't handle the number of requests per second. The requests are one per Magic card, they're cached, and they're spaced out. What should I do?

[GitHub](https://github.com/mcandre/proxymang)

Comment: What kind of numbers are you finding that YQL can't handle? Which YQL service are you using, the public endpoint or OAuthed one? (The latter gives an order of magnitude more requests per unit time.) Are any of the responses from YQL expected to be identical (results from YQLs own cache don't count towards limits)?

Comment: Feel free to browse Proxymang's GitHub source. I'm using a YQL plugin for jQuery, not sure how to authenticate YQL. Yes, often the responses are identical.

Comment: Without knowing the number of requests per second that you're seeing trouble with, any suggestions would be just based on guess-work and best-practices for YQL.  YQL is fairly liberal with the rate limiting, do you know how many requests per second you're currently achieving and how many you want to be able to get? Are you even sure you're being rate limited by YQL and not seeing some other strange behaviour?

Comment: Look at the GitHub code. The requests should be spaced out using sleep(), but I'm not sure if they are actually spaced out. If rate limiting isn't the problem, then I'm really lost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I never resolved the problem; I eventually decided to use the Gatherer's [meager](http://www.yellosoft.us/proxymang/proxymang.js) API instead.

The problem seems to one of the following:

- YQL blacklisted YelloSoft after too many requests/second
- MagicCards.info blacklisted YQL after too many requests/second
- MagicCards.info has a strict robots.txt which blocks HTML scraping, but not always